# Batch - Right String in foor Loop with variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i've a little problem with an right string manipulation in a for loop. This is the code in question:

**SET filename=!filename:~0,%LengthToclip%!**

If i try it without the loop or replace the variable %LengthToclip% with an fix number its works very fine. I need the For-Loop. Its processed a text file line by line, cut out unimportant information (the code fragment) on the right side and write it in an new text file.

My first idea was that i need something that ist stronger then the exclamation mark like its stronger than %. But i'm very newbie with batch so i have no idea how i could resolve my problem. Would be very grateful for help.

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%Z in ("!LengthToclip!") do SET "filename=!filename:~0,%%~Z!"
```